# Don't Work JS Audio Random Sounds

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm create audio button. The sound will start when we click on the button and we will click again stop it. I want random uninterrupted sound when we press the button. I created a sample JS, but when the sound ends, the sound does not change automatically.

I recently tried the code below. When I use this code, the button is starting to sound(okey), the sound is changing(okey), but when we pause click, the sound is not stopping. The sound changes, the sound changes again when we click again. What kind of method should I try?

```js
    var sounds = new Array();
            sounds[0]="http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/background/background001.mp3";
            sounds[1]="http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/background/background002.mp3";
            sounds[2]="http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/background/background003.mp3";   
            sounds[3]="http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/background/background004.mp3";
            sounds[4]="http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/background/background005.mp3";
            
 
 
 document.getElementById("playpause").addEventListener("click", function getRandomSounds(){
 var audio = document.getElementById('testAudio');
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
    document.getElementById("testAudio").src = sounds[randomNum];
 

 
  if(this.className == 'is-playing'){
    this.className = "";
    this.innerHTML = "Pause"
    audio.pause();
 
  }else{
    this.className = "is-playing";
    this.innerHTML = "Play";
    audio.play();

  }

   document.getElementById("testAudio").addEventListener("ended", getRandomSounds);
   getRandomSounds();
   
});
```

```html
 <html>
 <body>
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="playpause" name="check" />
    <label for="playpause" tabindex=1></label>
 <audio id="testAudio"></audio>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**try removing the following this code:**

```
document.getElementById("testAudio").addEventListener("ended", 
getRandomSounds);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there were a few logical problems with the solution you had.  The biggest ones were confusion with referencing elements for checkbox vs. label (so I simplified to a button), and that you were using the same event for play/pause as you were for queing the next item.  So, as soon as it would try to queue one, it would also pause.

```
<html>

  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Play" id="playpause">
    <audio id="testAudio"></audio>
  </body>

</html>


   var sounds = new Array();
   sounds[0] = "http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/background/background001.mp3";
   sounds[1] = "http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/background/background002.mp3";
   sounds[2] = "http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/background/background003.mp3";
   sounds[3] = "http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/background/background004.mp3";
   sounds[4] = "http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/background/background005.mp3";



   document.getElementById("playpause").addEventListener("click", function() {

     var audio = document.getElementById('testAudio');

     var doPlay = this.className != 'is-playing' && audio.src != null;

     if (audio.src == null) {
       getRandomSound();
     }

     if (this.className == 'is-playing') {
       this.className = "";
       this.value = "Play"
       audio.pause();

     } else if(doPlay) {
       this.className = "is-playing";
       this.value = "Pause"
       audio.play();
     }

     document.getElementById("testAudio").addEventListener("ended", getRandomSounds);


   });

   function getRandomSound() {
     var audio = document.getElementById('testAudio');
     var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
     document.getElementById("testAudio").src = sounds[randomNum];

     audio.play();

   };
```

I also updated it here so that the pause is just a pause and won't change the selected track until the one you're on has ended.  I'm not sure if that's the intended or not, but by the description, I'm guessing that's what you'd want.  Otherwise, it's a simple edit to go to a new track on every new start.

Comment: Thank you... I tried the code but it did not work. Is not it possible to solve this problem without creating a button? I want a simple interface.

Comment: I tried something like this with your codes. After the sound is finished, a random sound starts, but then it stops again. where is the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/rpo99Ltp/

Comment: this even uses the checkbox https://jsfiddle.net/VeritoAnimus/safL4wfc/  The button is just simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a reasonable amount with playing sound from the browser, and the best option I found was to use a soundmanager js.  I used SoundManager2 from here: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/template/ I'm sure there are others that would work though.  The problem is that different browsers have different capabilities and expectations, so in order to get a best-case working scenario, you need something that uses html5 with flash as a backup option.  I can verify that the one I linked works in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome (desktop and mobile), but I can't verify any other browsers for certain.  I've been using it for audio responses in a warehouse application, so I can also verify that it's reliable when implemented correctly, but I haven't used play/pause on it or the interface.  I just play from the background.

here's my setup as an implementation example if you end up working with that one:

```
var soundReady = false;
var QueuedSounds = [];

soundManager.setup({
    url: '/Scripts/SoundManager/',
    // flashVersion: 9, // optional: shiny features (default = 8)
    preferFlash: false,
    onready: function () {
        // Ready to use; soundManager.createSound() etc. can now be called.
        soundReady = true;
        QueuedSounds.Each(function (s) {
            var mysound = soundManager.createSound({
                id: 'mySound',
                url: s.filename,
                autoLoad: true,
                autoPlay: true,
                onfinish: function () {
                    this.destruct();
                },
                volume: 100
            });

        });
    }
});


function PlaySound(filename, mime) {
    if (soundObject != null) {
        $(soundObject).remove();
        soundObject.removed = true;
        soundObject = null;
    }
    if (soundReady) {
        var mysound = soundManager.createSound({
            id: 'mySound',
            url: filename,
            autoLoad: true,
            autoPlay: true,
            onfinish: function () {
                this.destruct();
            },
            volume: 100
        });
    }
    else {
        QueuedSounds.push({ filename: filename, mime: mime });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Actually, I'd like to know what I missed above.